# copy values from one sheet to another one fast way code no performance

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code and I would like to make it faster to copy values from source sheet to destination sheet. Many thanks. Any help, please!

My code is not really performant. it takes very long time to copy my values and it's wort. thank you for taking time to learn my post.

```
Sub BRM_ID1()
Dim SourceData As Worksheet


Set SourceData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SZCategoryData")

Dim TailoredData As Worksheet
Set TailoredData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SZCategory tailored")

Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To 1000
    Dim j As Long

    For j = 4 To 1000

         If SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "BRM_ID" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
            TailoredData.Cells(j, 2).Value = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
        ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "RELEASE" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then

            TailoredData.Cells(j, 9).Value = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)


        ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "PCP TYPE" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
            TailoredData.Cells(j, 3).Value = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)

        ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "RELEASE" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
            TailoredData.Cells(j, 9).Value = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)

        ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "BRM REQ ID" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
            TailoredData.Cells(j, 4).Value = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)

        ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "PCP FLAG 2" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
            TailoredData.Cells(j, 7).Value = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
        ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "UAT DROP" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
            TailoredData.Cells(j, 8).Value = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)
        ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "1A WORKPACKAGE" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
            TailoredData.Cells(j, 6).Value = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)

        ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "PCP FLAG" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
            TailoredData.Cells(j, 13).Value = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)

        ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "WN TYPE" And SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then
            TailoredData.Cells(j, 10).Value = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)




End If

    Next
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: Why the c++ tag ? I can't see anyting c++-related in the question.

Comment: it is done in c++  in the same way !! Sorry if it is disturbing you !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Macro performance is too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806308/vba-macro-performance-is-too-slow)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disabling calculations while you are running the loop?

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
// Your code
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Everytime you update a cell, the entire worsheet gets update, making the process not really performant

If you need to trigger a manual calculation, call the `calculate` method ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-calculate-method-excel))

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me very much!

Answer (score 0):

First sorry for my bad english. 
I think this could Help. But the performance of Vba is a difficult thing.

- In the first place you should reduce your IF-Statement.
- Secondly you should not declare your variable in the For-loop.
- thirdly if you do not want to search much more lines, an integer is enough. You dont need a Long.
- fourthly as the previous speaker said use Application.Calculation
- and I would advise you to use Select case. Only because of the clarity, for the perfomence it makes no difference

here the adapted code:

```
Sub BRM_ID1()

    Dim SourceData As Worksheet
    Set SourceData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SZCategoryData")
    Dim TailoredData As Worksheet
    Set TailoredData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SZCategory tailored")

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    For i = 2 To 1000

        For j = 4 To 1000

            If SourceData.Cells(i, 1).Value = TailoredData.Cells(j, 1) Then

                    If SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "BRM_ID" Then

                        TailoredData.Cells(j, 2).Value = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)

                    ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "RELEASE" Then

                        TailoredData.Cells(j, 9).Value = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)

                    ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "PCP TYPE" Then

                        TailoredData.Cells(j, 3).Value = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)

                    ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "RELEASE" Then

                        TailoredData.Cells(j, 9).Value = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)

                    ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "BRM REQ ID" Then

                        TailoredData.Cells(j, 4).Value = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)

                    ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "PCP FLAG 2" Then

                        TailoredData.Cells(j, 7).Value = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)

                    ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "UAT DROP" Then

                        TailoredData.Cells(j, 8).Value = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)

                    ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "1A WORKPACKAGE" Then

                        TailoredData.Cells(j, 6).Value = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)

                    ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "PCP FLAG" Then

                        TailoredData.Cells(j, 13).Value = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)

                    ElseIf SourceData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "WN TYPE" Then

                        TailoredData.Cells(j, 10).Value = SourceData.Cells(i, 5)

                    End If
            End If

        Next
    Next

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

I hope it helps. ask at questions.